# iTunes Match Songs Don't Appear on iPhone

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, iphone

My iPhone 5S says it has synced with iTunes Match but some music is missing from the iPhone.  I have Show All Music turned on.  Is there some way to debug what is happening?

Comment: Are they grayed out or completely gone?

Comment: Example:  I have the AC/DC album "Who Made Who" on my MBP.  I ripped it from the actual CD.  iTunes on the MBP says the album is "Uploaded", but it doesn't download to the library on my iPhone.  It's not that I can see it on my phone but it's grayed out...it's just not there.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure you have all the **necessary settings** turned on, make sure you have:

1. The latest version of iOS
2. Navigate to `Settings > Music > iCloud Music Library` and turn it on;

Also, make sure you are connected to a WiFi network (*the default behaviour of Music app is to only allow music downloads through WiFi*). If you don't have a WiFI connection, enable Data Downloads navigating to `Settings > Music > Use Mobile Data` and turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

I've having this issue for long time. Go to iPhone icon and pressing sync button mostly works on me.

Answer (score -2):

Probably these missing songs weren't correctly uploaded from iTunes to cloud. Try re-scan you iTunes library and re-uploading it. Tell me how it goes, I'm having a lot of issues with iTunes Match.